# Viewing Composite Document File V2 Documents

Tags: windows, ms-office

Every now and then I receive attachments from Windows users that show up as "Picture (Device independent Bitmap)" and - when I run "file" on the command line, they are identified as "Composite Document File V2 Document".

I guess they are screenshots - what would be the best way to view them on a Mac?

Thanks.

Comment: When you Control-Click on the item, what shows up in the Open With menu? Preview? How about Safari? Device Independent Bitmaps are BMPs, a common Windows picture format. You might even be able to view them with QuickLook.

Comment: I get preview as the default application, and then an error message that says: "The file “foo.bmp” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output from `file` I'd suggest that you try [`unoconv`](http://freecode.com/projects/unoconv/) to convert it to something your system can open.